# Scheme continuation restarting in weird place

Tags: scope, scheme, racket, continuations, callcc

**UPDATE:**

So the issue seems to be with the generator, and not necessarily with the next-token and lookahead functions.  I added some display calls around where the set!s were happening, and found that the issue is that after (generate-token) is called the second time, it resumes execution from where it was called the first time.

Here's the full code for the program (I've left the original post below for reference):

```
(define char-alphanumeric? (lambda (char) (or (char-alphabetic? char) (char-numeric? char))))

(define generate-token #f)
(define filename "input.txt")

(define next-token #f)
(define lookahead #f)
(define status #f)

(let ((f (open-input-file filename)) (yield #f) (token "") (lookahead-token #f) (current-token #f))
  (set! generate-token (lambda ()
                     (letrec ((next-char (lambda (c)
                                            (let ((separators (list #\; #\,)))
                                              (cond ((eof-object? c) (display "last token before eof: ") (display token) (newline) (yield c))
                                                    ((member c separators)
                                                     (begin
                                                            (display "token before sep: ") (display token) (newline)
                                                            (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (resume)
                                                                                              (set! generate-token (lambda () (resume)))
                                                                                              (yield token)))
                                                            (display "back from call") (set! token "")
                                                            (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (resume)
                                                                                              (set! generate-token (lambda () (resume)))
                                                                                              (yield (make-string 1 c))))
                                                            ))
                                                    ((or (char-alphanumeric? c) (equal? c #\_)) ; c is part of a string token
                                                     (begin (display "found char: ") (display c) (display "; added to string: ")
                                                            (set! token (string-append token (make-string 1 c)))
                                                            (display token) (newline)
                                                            (next-char (read-char f))))
                                                    ((char-whitespace? c)
                                                     (begin
                                                            (display "token before ws: ") (display token) (newline)
                                                            (if (> (string-length token) 0)
                                                                (begin (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (resume)
                                                                                              (display "setting generate-token to resume") (newline)
                                                                                              (set! generate-token (lambda ()
                                                                                                                 ((display "calling resume") (newline)
                                                                                                                 (resume))))
                                                                                              (display "yielding token from cc") (newline)
                                                                                              (yield token)))
                                                                 (display "continuing...") (newline)
                                                                (set! token ""))
                                                                ;(set! token "")
                                                                ))))
                                              (next-char (read-char f))
                                              ))))
                       (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (k) ((set! yield k) (k (next-char (read-char f))))))
                       )))
  (set! lookahead (lambda () (begin
                              (if (not lookahead-token)
                                  (begin (display "no lookahead") (newline)
                                         (display "setting lookahead-token") (newline)
                                         (set! lookahead-token (string-copy (generate-token)))
                                         (display "lookahead set to ") (display lookahead-token) (newline)
                                         ))
                             lookahead-token)))
  (set! next-token (lambda () (begin
                               (if lookahead-token
                                  (begin (display "affirmative") (newline)
                                         (set! current-token (string-copy lookahead-token))
                                         (set! lookahead-token #f))
                                  (begin (display "negative") (newline)
                                         (display "setting current token to next-token") (newline)
                                         (set! current-token (string-copy (generate-token)))
                                         (display "current token = ") (display current-token) (newline)
                                         (set! lookahead-token #f)))
                               current-token)))
  (set! status (lambda () (begin (display current-token) (display " -> ") (display lookahead-token) (newline))))
)
```

Executing the next-token and lookahead calls as per the first example in the original post below yields:

```
> (next-token)
negative
setting current token to next-token
found char: t; added to string: t
found char: h; added to string: th
found char: e; added to string: the
found char: s; added to string: thes
found char: e; added to string: these
token before ws: these
setting generate-token to resume
yielding token from cc
current token = these
"these"
> (status)
these -> #f
> (lookahead)
no lookahead
setting lookahead-token
calling resume
continuing...
found char: a; added to string: a
found char: r; added to string: ar
found char: e; added to string: are
token before ws: are
setting generate-token to resume
yielding token from cc ; the problem is right here: the generate token call is
current token = are    ; sending control back to next-token instead of lookahead.
"are"
> (status)
are -> #f
```

I'm at a loss as to why it's behaving this way, but will admit that I am new to continuations and probably don't fully understand the ramifications.  Any help, as always, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Original post follows:

---

I've created a generator that parses a text file and returns one token at0 a time as strings.  So, if I have a file that contains

```
these are my file contents
```

Successive calls to (generate-token) return "these" "are" "my" ... respectively.  This seems to be working, but what I've written this as part of a parser for a larger assignment.  The generator seems to be working smoothly, but as I am building an LR(1) parser to parse the stream of tokens, I need to be able to perform a lookahead.  To that end, I've created the following program:

```
(define generate-token #f)
(define next-token #f)
(define lookahead #f)
(define status #f)

(let ((lookahead-token #f) (current-token #f))
  (set! generate-token (lambda () ... ) ; the generator function
  (set! lookahead (lambda () (begin
                              (if (not lookahead-token)
                                  (begin (display "no lookahead") (newline)
                                   (set! lookahead-token (string-copy (generate-token)))))
                             lookahead-token)))
  (set! next-token (lambda () (begin
                               (if lookahead-token
                                  (begin (display "affirmative") (newline)
                                         (set! current-token (string-copy lookahead-token))
                                         (set! lookahead-token #f))
                                  (begin (display "negative") (newline)
                                         (set! current-token (string-copy (generate-token)))
                                         (set! lookahead-token #f)))
                                  current-token)))
  (set! status (lambda () (begin (display current-token) (display " -> ") (display lookahead-token) (newline))))
)
```

However, these don't work as expected.  I am under the impression that scheme (this is written in drRacket, but using #lang r5rs) passes objects by value, so the (string-copy calls are hypothetically unnecessary, but this still doesn't work as expected.  It works like so:

```
> (status)
#f -> #f
> (next-token)
"these"
> (status) ; next-token properly sets current-token 
"these" -> #f
> (lookahead) ; generator returns "are" as expected
"are"
> (status) ; notice that the current-token has been replaced instead of the lookahead-token 
"are" -> #f
```

In a different flow, if (lookahead) is called first, it works correctly.

```
> (status)
#f -> #f
> (lookahead)
"these"
> (status)
#f -> "these"
> (lookahead)
"these"
> (status)
#f -> "these"
> (next-token)
"these"
> (status)
"these" -> #f
> (lookahead)
"are"
> (status)
"these" -> "are"
```

If anyone has any clue as to what's going on, any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Disclosure: this is school work, but I'm not asking you to do it for me >.>.

Comment: Your code doesn't match what you show later -- in the code, these functions use `set!` and therefore they don't return any useful value.  (And the printouts are not in the repl example too.)

Comment: "I am under the impression that scheme passes objects by value, so the (string-copy calls are hypothetically unnecessary" No, Scheme does pass things by value, but these values are references. The string that a variable references may still be modified. Scheme strings are mutable (with string-set!), so string-copy *is* necessary in general. But since you don't mutate any strings here, it is not necessary.

Comment: @Eli you are correct.  I mis-copied the code to exclude the final "current-token)))" in the next-token function (it matches the return of the lookahead-token in the lookahead function).  I don't know how I managed that.  I've added the return statement, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this?  (I've just been browsing the [tag:continuations] tag since there was a recent generator related question, [call-with-current-continuation - state saving concept](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24183566/1281433).)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your implementation of `yield`. Here's a simplified version of your implementation for readability:

```
(define yield #f)
(define my-generator
        (lambda ()
           (let forever ((num 0))
               (let/cc resume
                  (set! my-generator resume)
                  (yield num))
               (forever (add1 num)))))

(define zero (let/cc my-yield
                (set! yield my-yield)
                (my-generator)))
(define one (my-generator))
zero
;; => 1
```

A continuation always jumps back to where its return value was originally going. So if you capture `yield` with `call/cc` or `let/cc`, then every time you `yield` you'll jump back to where you captured it.

In your code, you took the time to update your resume continuation before each `yield`, but you only update `yield` in one place where you're about
to call `next-token`. You need to update `yield` every time you're about to call `generate-token`.

For those readers who aren't doing this for school, just use `racket/generator`, in which all the work and more is done for you.