# call-with-current-continuation - state saving concept

Tags: scheme, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

After reading **The Seasoned Schemer** I felt I understood `call/cc` properly. But, after seeing some WOW tricks with `call/cc` I found I was wrong.

```
(define cc 0)
(define (f)
  (call/cc (lambda (k)
             (set! cc k)
             3)))

(+ 1 2 4 (f)) ; eval's to 10
(cc 13) ; eval's to 20
```

That perfectly match my understanding. I think when I reach a `call/cc` call I am just saving the program state. and calling the function next to it with a function. If that function (`k`) is called from somewhere than I just replacing the entire `(call/cc ...)` stuff with the parameter given to it. **The above program seems to worked that way too**

---

But,

```
(define (itr lst)
  (define (state k)
    (for-each (lambda (item)
                (call/cc (lambda (h)
                           (set! state h)
                           (k item))))
              lst)
    (k 'done))

  (define (generator)
    (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))
  generator)

(define (next)
  (itr (range 2)))
```

Calling `next` 3 times produces 0, 1 and `'done`. That means when `state` used the function `k` given by `generator` it didn't restore the state of the program. **I just showed you I tried to understand it.**

---

So, how does `call/cc` actually work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### With Continuation Passing Style (without `call/cc`)

It may be easier to understand this example if you implement a version that uses explicit continuation passing style rather than `call/cc` first.  In this case, let's start with a continuation passing version of `map`:

```
(define (kmap fn list k)
  (if (null? list)
      (k list)
      (fn (car list)
          (lambda (head)
            (kmap fn
                  (cdr list)
                  (lambda (tail)
                    (k (cons head tail))))))))
```

```
(define (identity x) x)

(kmap (lambda (x k) (k (+ 1 x))) '(1 2 3 4) identity)
;=> (2 3 4 5)
```

If you're not familiar with continuation passing style, this may be a bit to wrap your head around, but it's not too too hard.  Remember that `kmap` and `fn` each take an additional parameter at the end that should be called with "the result".  So when we call `fn` with `(car list)`, we also pass it a procedure `(lambda (head) ...)` that's responsible for taking care of the rest of the mapping for us.  The rest of the mapping is defined in terms of `kmap` again.  Each call to `kmap` takes a final continuation that expects to receive the list that results from mapping `fn` over the list.

Now, since we can see how a mapping can be implemented with continuation passing style, we can write an iterator generation procedure using it.  The procedure `iterator` takes a list and returns a procedure that we can call to get each element of `list`.

```
(define (iterator list)
  (define (next k)
    (kmap (lambda (item more-next)
            (set! next more-next)
            (k item))
          list
          (lambda (results)
            (k 'done))))
  (lambda ()
    (next identity)))
```

```
> (define get (iterator '(1 2)))
> (get)
1
> (get)
2
> (get)
done
> (get)
done
```

```
> (define get (iterator '(a b c)))
> (get)
a
> (get)
b
> (get)
c
> (get)
done
> (get)
done
```

The trick here is that we define a local procedure `next`.  It calls `kmap` with a procedure that *redefines* `next` when each element of `list` is processed to be the procedure that will process the remaining part of `list`.  After redefining `next`, it calls `k` with the element.  The final continuation passed to `kmap` actually ignores the results passed to it, and just calls `k` with the symbol `done`.  What we *return* from `iterator` is not the value of `next`, but a procedure that calls `next` with the continuation `identity`.  The indirection here means that we always call the *latest* value of `next` with `identity`.  Passing `identity` as the continuation means that we just get the list element back.

### With `call/cc`

Now that we see how can we do this *without* `call/cc`, we're better equipped to see how we can use `call/cc` to do it.  Recall the definition from the question:

```
(define (itr lst)
  (define (state k)
    (for-each (lambda (item)
                (call/cc (lambda (h)
                           (set! state h)
                           (k item))))
              lst)
    (k 'done))

  (define (generator)                   
    (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))   
                                        
  generator)
```

#### Returning the generator

First note that

```
  (define (generator)
    (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))

  generator
```

can be simplified to

```
(lambda () (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))
```

and that's just about what we did in our implementation.  When you're calling this from the REPL, all that the `k` wants to do is get the value and return it (and print it).  In our version, we approximate that by simply returning it unchanged.  That is, we use `identity`, and we used the name `next` instead of `state`.  So

```
(lambda () (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))
```

is just like

```
(lambda () (next identity))
```

#### The `state` (or `next`) procedure

The rest of it

```
  (define (state k)
    (for-each (lambda (item)
                (call/cc (lambda (h)
                           (set! state h)
                           (k item))))
              lst)
    (k 'done))
```

is very similar to what we did, too.  Instead of using `kmap` and a `fn` that takes two arguments (the item and the continuation), we use `for-each` which takes a procedure of a single argument (the item) and inside that procedure, we use `call/cc` to grab the continuation.  So

```
(for-each
  (lambda (item)
    (call/cc (lambda (h)
               ...
```

is just like

```
(kmap (lambda (item h)
        ...
```

`for-each` doesn't need a final continuation argument, so we can't pass the result-ignoring `(lambda () (k 'done))`.  Instead, we just call `(k 'done)` *after* the `for-each` call.  That is,

```
(for-each fn list)
(k 'done)
```

is just like

```
(kmap fn
      list
      (lambda (result)
        (k 'done)))
```

### Saving program state

In both of these implementations, you're "saving the program state" in some sense.  The important state that you're saving is the one that will continue iterating over the list.

Comment: Now I know what continuation is. I worked with `collector` (the little schemer used this term) before so the `kmap` was not a problem. The only thing that give me pain again was `(set! next more-next)`. Now that is a history. I see, you are one of these people who can express idea's easily. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion that something is wrong is correct. The code is totally broken, and this is obvious from the fact that the generator fails to capture a new continuation for the mainline program whenever it is invoked to call the item. Or rather, it fumbles and throws that continuation away. The result is that the wrong continuation is called on the attempt to get the second item, resulting in an infinite loop.

Firstly, let's correct something from the wording of your question. Calling `next` doesn't yield items; calling `next` yields the generator function. The way `next` is supposed to be used is exemplified like this:

```
(let ((g (next)))
  (list (g) (g) (g)))  ;; should return (0 1 done)
```

But, in fact it cannot work. Let's examine it:

```
(define (itr lst)
  (define (state k)
    (for-each (lambda (item)
                (call/cc (lambda (h)
                           (set! state h)
                           (k item))))
              lst)
    (k 'done))

  (define (generator)
    (call/cc (lambda (k) (state k))))
  generator)

(define (next)
  (itr (range 2)))
```

Let's trace through what is happening.

**The setup:** When `(next)` is called, the expression `(iter (range 2))` returns `generator`, a closure captured in an environment where the `itr`, `lst` and `state` variables are bound.

**The first iteration:** The first call to the generator returned by `next` therefore invokes `generator`. Now `generator` captures its own continuation, which appears as `k` in the `lambda`, and passes it to `state`. So then `state` runs, and has `generator`'s continuation bound to `k`.  It enters into the first iteration, and saves its own state by replacing itself with a new continuation: `(set! state h)`. At this point, the previous binding of `state` to the `define`-d function is overwritten; `state` is now a continuation function to resume the `for-each`.  The next step is to yield the `item` back to the `k` continuation, which brings us back to `generator` which returns the item. Great, so that's how the first item appears out of the first call to `(next)`.

**The second iteration:** From here on, things go wrong. The second call to the generator that was returned by `next` again, captures a continuation again and invokes `state` which is now the continuation of the generating co-routine. The generator passes its own continuation into `state`. But `state` is no longer the function that was `define`-d by `itr`! **And so the newly captured continuation in `generator` does not connect with the `k` parameter that is in the lexical scope of the `for-each`.** When `(k item)` is called to yield the second item, this `k` still refers to the original `k` binding which holds the originally captured continuation in the first call to `generator`. **This is analogous to a backwards goto and results in non-terminating behavior**.

Here is how we can fix it:

```
(define (itr lst)
  (define yield '()) ;; forward definition (could use let for this).

  (define (state)    ;; k parameter is gone
    (for-each (lambda (item)
                (call/cc (lambda (h)
                           (set! state h)
                           (yield item))))  ;; call yield, not k
              lst)
    (yield 'done))  ;; yield, not k.

  (define (generator)
    (call/cc (lambda (self) 
               (set! yield self) ;; save new escape on each call
               (state))))
  generator)

;; test
(let ((g (itr (range 2))) ;; let's eliminate the "next" wrapper
  (display (list (g) (g) (g))))
```

The output is `(0 1 done)`.