# How to implement Python-style generator in Scheme (Racket or ChezScheme)?

Tags: scheme

today I solve the N-queen problem using Scheme but it is extremely slow compared to the same version of Python. when N = 8, Scheme takes 90+ seconds! I know one reason is that I can't use a generator in Scheme, my code has to form large lists first, which is a nightmare for memory and calculation.

There is few topics about generator in Scheme, [this one](http://journal.thobe.org/2009/04/python-style-generators-in-scheme.html) is the only one I found maybe useful but sadly it doesn't work in both racket or chez scheme.

Actually, I just want a simple version of python generator, that is, do not form the whole list, just send me one value at one time. i.e:

```
(range 100000) ; will consume a large memory

(define g (generator 100000)) ; will do nothing
(next g) ;0 <-you call it with next one time, it returns one value
(next g) ;1
;...
(next g) ;100000
(next g) ;return a value that indicates the end, such as #f.
```

If this is hard, any related links or similar implementation topics are also appreciated. I'm really tired of searching. Thanks!

This is my N-queen Scheme code, if needed:

```
(define (range n)
    (define (recur n)
        (if (= n -1)
            '()
            (cons n (recur (- n 1)))))
    (recur (- n 1)))

(define (flatten a)
    (if (null? a)
        '()
        (append (car a) (flatten (cdr a)))))

(define (safe? x y sln)
    (if (null? sln)
        #t
        (let ((px (car (car sln))) (py (cadr (car sln))))
            (if (or (= y py) (= (- py y) (- px x)) (= (- py y) (- x px)))
                #f 
                (safe? x y (cdr sln))))))

(define (nqueen n)
    (define (recur x)
        (if (= x -1)
            (list '())
            (flatten (map (lambda (y) (map (lambda (sln) (cons (list x y) sln)) (filter (lambda (sln) (safe? x y sln)) (recur (- x 1))))) (range n)))))
    (recur (- n 1)))

(define (pl a)
    (if (null? a)
        '()
        (begin (display (car a)) (display "\n") (pl (cdr a)))))

(pl (nqueen 4))
```

Comment: You may find a solution in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187513/1281433) to [call-with-current-continuation - state saving concept](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24183566/1281433).  It's not quite a duplicate, but it shows how to implement a function that returns successive values in successive calls.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor Thanks. I will study it.

Comment: As I read your question in a bit more detail, I think that the simple solution Óscar provides may suffice for your particular needs.  The link I provided touches more on the general question in the title "How to implement Python-style generator in Scheme".  For a simple range generator, it's easy, because the state of the generation process is so simple.  For more complex things, it's nice to have fuller power of continuations.

Comment: generators are equivalent to lazy lists. It is extremely easy to define non-memoizing, SICP styled lazy lists in Scheme, and they are sufficient for many problems -- I'd hazard a guess that for queens problem too. See the second half [of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12111632/849891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using continuations for this case (as suggested in the link) is unjustified. Here's a simpler idea: let's define our generator as a thunk (a no-args function) that stores as part of its environment the starting point, the maximum allowed value, the increment and the current element. Every time we call the procedure, the current element will be updated. The following code behaves similar to Python 3.x [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function (or Python 2.x [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)):

```
(define (generator start stop step)
  (let ((current (- start 1)))
    (lambda ()
      (cond ((>= current stop) #f)
            (else
             (set! current (+ current step))
             current)))))
```

Now the `next` procedure will simply call the generator until the maximum value is reached, at this point the generator will start returning `#f` for each subsequent call:

```
(define (next generator)
  (generator))
```

For example:

```
(define g (generator 0 3 1))
(next g) ; 0
(next g) ; 1
(next g) ; 2
(next g) ; 3
(next g) ; #f
```

Another alternative would be to use streams, but I'll stick with the above solution, it's simple enough and should work on any Scheme interpreter. And yet another alternative - if you're coding in Racket, just use a [sequence](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html) (which is also a stream), like this:

```
(for ([i (in-range 0 4 1)])
  (display i))

=> 0123
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a make-iterator procedure using guile prompts to implement spidermonkey generators (similar but not identical to ECMAScript 6 generators).  Since racket also has prompts this should be directly translatable to racket's call-with-continuation-prompt and abort-current-continuation in place of guile's call-with-prompt and abort-to-prompt.

Here is the code:

```
;; this procedure takes a generator procedure, namely a procedure
;; which has a 'yield' parameter for its first or only argument,
;; followed by such other arguments (other than the one for the
;; 'yield' parameter) as the generator procedure requires, and
;; constructs an iterator from them.  When the iterator is invoked, it
;; will begin executing the procedure unless and until the argument
;; comprising the yield procedure is called, which will cause the
;; iterator to suspend computation and instead return the value passed
;; to yield (yield is a procedure taking one argument).  If invoked
;; again, the iterator will resume computation at the point where it
;; last left off (returning a list of the values, if any, passed to
;; the iterator on resuming).  When the generator procedure has
;; executed to the end, the iterator returns 'stop-iteration.  This
;; procedure is intentionally modelled on javascript/spider-monkey
;; generators.  It has some resemblance to call/ec, except that (i)
;; instead of executing the passed procedure immediately, it returns
;; an iterator which will do so, (ii) it is resumable, and (iii) the
;; procedure to be executed can receive starting arguments in addition
;; to the yield/break argument, to provide an alternative to binding
;; them with a lambda closure.
(define (make-iterator proc . args)
  (define tag (make-prompt-tag))
  (define send-back '())
  (define (thunk)
    (apply proc
           (lambda (val)
             (abort-to-prompt tag val)
             send-back)
           args)
    ;; the generator procedure has returned - reset thunk to do
    ;; nothing except return 'stop-iteration and return
    ;; 'stop-iteration after this last call to proc
    (set! thunk (lambda () 'stop-iteration))
    'stop-iteration)
  (lambda send-args
    (set! send-back send-args)
    (call-with-prompt tag
                      thunk
                      (lambda (cont ret)
                        (set! thunk cont)
                        ret))))
```

Here are procedures for pipe-lining:

```
;; for-iter iterates until the iterator passed to it (as constructed
;; by make-iterator) returns 'stop-iteration.  It invokes the procedure
;; passed as a second argument with the value yielded by the iterator
;; on each iteration.  It is mainly used for composing lazy operations
;; by pipelining, as for example with lazy-map and lazy-filter.
(define (for-iter iter proc)
  (let loop()
    (let ([val (iter)])
      (if (not (eq? val 'stop-iteration))
          (begin
            (proc val)
            (loop))))))

;; lazy-map is a procedure which takes an input iterator constructed
;; by make-iterator and a standard procedure, and then returns another
;; iterator (the output iterator) which yields the values obtained by
;; applying the standard procedure to the input iterator's yielded
;; values.
(define (lazy-map iter proc)
  (make-iterator (lambda (yield)
                   (for-iter iter (lambda (val) (yield (proc val)))))))

;; lazy-filter is a procedure which takes an input iterator
;; constructed by make-iterator, and then returns another iterator
;; (the output iterator) which yields such of the values yielded by
;; the input iterator as are those for which the predicate proc
;; returns #t
(define (lazy-filter iter proc)
  (make-iterator (lambda (yield)
                   (for-iter iter (lambda (val) (if (proc val) (yield val)))))))
```

And here is the canonical counter example from p.280 of the 6th edition of the Rhino book:

```
(define (counter yield initial)
  (let loop ([next-value initial])
    (let ([increment (yield next-value)])
      (if (not (null? increment))
          (if (eq? (car increment) 'reset)
              (loop initial)
              (loop (+ next-value (car increment))))
          (loop (+ 1 next-value))))))

(define counter-iter (make-iterator counter 10))   ;; create iterator at 10
(display (counter-iter))(newline)                  ;; prints 10
(display (counter-iter 2))(newline)                ;; prints 12
(display (counter-iter 'reset))(newline)           ;; prints 10
```

I also have an anaphoric version as a macro, which injects a yield keyname into a body of code, but I prefer the approach above.

**Edit:**

For scheme implementations which do not support prompts, the following works identically to the version using prompts.  However with guile, prompts are more efficient than using full call/cc continuations (I guess that is not necessarily true for all implementations):

```
(define (make-iterator proc . args)
  (define prompt-cont #f)
  (define iter-cont #f)
  (define done #f)
  (define (yield arg)
    (call/cc
     (lambda (k)
       (set! iter-cont k)
       (prompt-cont arg))))
  (lambda send-back
    (if done
      'stop-iteration
      (call/cc
       (lambda (k)
         (set! prompt-cont k)
         (if iter-cont
           (iter-cont send-back)
           (begin
              (apply proc yield args)
              (set! done #t)
              (prompt-cont 'stop-iteration))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Classical sequences can be implemented in ChezScheme in a few lines. Here is my version:

```
(library (seq)
  (export seq hd tl range smap force-seq for)
  (import (scheme))

  (define-syntax seq
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ a b) (cons a (delay b)))))

  (define hd car)
  (define (tl s) (force (cdr s)))

  (define (range-impl a b s)
    (cond ((< a b) (seq a (range-impl (+ a s) b s)))
          (else    '())))


  (define (range a . b)
    (cond ((null? b)       (range-impl 0 a 1))
          ((null? (cdr b)) (range-impl a (car b) 1))
          (else            (range-impl a (car b) (cadr b)))))

  (define (smap f s)
    (cond ((null? s) '())
          (else      (seq (f (hd s)) (smap f (tl s))))))

  (define (force-seq s)
    (when (not (null? s))
      (force-seq (tl s))))

  (define-syntax for
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ v r body ...) (force-seq (smap (lambda (v) body ...) r)))))
)
```

The usage:

```
(import (seq))
(for x (range 5 12)
  (display x)
  (newline))
```

Using sequences it's easy to read lines from file in python way:

```
(library (io)
  (export getline lines)
  (import (scheme))
  (import (seq))

  (define (getline ip)
    (define (copy-line)
      (let ((c (get-char ip)))
        (unless (or (eof-object? c)
                    (eqv? c '#\newline))
          (display c)
          (copy-line))))
    (let ((c (peek-char ip)))
      (cond ((eof-object? c) #f)
            (else (with-output-to-string copy-line)))))


    (define (lines ip)
      (let ((l (getline ip)))
        (cond (l    (seq l (lines ip)))
              (else '()))))
)
```

Then one can write:

```
(import (seq))
(import (io))

(for l (lines (current-input-port))
  (display l)
  (newline))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that [`do`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html?q=in-list#%25_idx_140) performs significantly more quickly than iterating over a list:

```
(do ((i 0 (add1 i)))
  ((= i 100000) 'result)
   (some-function! i some-data))
```

If you want to be more functional the Racket documentation suggests [`in-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-list#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-list%29%29) for use with `for` and it's variants.

```
(for/list ((i (in-list (range 0 100000))))
  (some-function i some-data))
```